# How to set the focus on the next/previous cell inside a DataGrid? Especially after calling grid.CommitEdit()?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I've a custom combobox template because of some binding stuff that won't work with the 'default' ComboBoxColumn.

To make it look 'nice' I've one template for the edit mode (a Combobox) and one for the 'normal' mode (a Label).

Now, because of that I've to commit the edit made to the combobox manually inside the CellEditEnding event

```
private bool changeCommitInProgress = false;     
private void table_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.EditingElement is ContentPresenter && e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
                {
                    if (!changeCommitInProgress)
                    {
                        changeCommitInProgress = true;
                        DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
                        grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, false);
                        changeCommitInProgress = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem with this is, that it'll remove the focus from the entire datagrid. Just to be on the safe side, these are the only properties I changed on the datagrid (aside from the Name property and the ItemsSource):

```
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
grid.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun question. I have done similar with a nested DataList where I had to add a new row after last entry and focus on the first textbox of the newly generated row, maybe you can extrapolate my strategy to fit your situation?

```
protected void calcAvg(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int row = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString()) - 1;
    DataListItem ActiveRow = dlMeasurements.Items[row];

// Snipped code doing stuff with current row
// Compare how many rows completed to number of rows requested
if (!(row + 1 == Convert.ToInt32(txtSample.Text)))
{
    // Create new row
    DataRow drNew = nextMeas.Tables[0].NewRow();
    nextMeas.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drNew);

    // Change item index and rebind
    dlMeasurements.EditItemIndex = row + 1;
    dlMeasurements.DataSource = nextMeas.Tables[0];
    dlMeasurements.DataBind();

    //Set focus with the Script Manager
    smInspection.SetFocus((TextBox)(dlMeasurements.Items[row + 1].FindControl("txtRead1")));
}
else
{
    // Otherwise close the measurements and show exit button
    dlMeasurements.EditItemIndex = -1;
    dlMeasurements.DataSource = nextMeas.Tables[0];
    dlMeasurements.DataBind();
    btnSaveAndPrint.Visible = true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Oh, the function is called from datalist like <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCalcAvg" runat="server" Text="" CommandName="calcAvg" OnCommand="calcAvg"
                                                        CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>' />

Comment: ah, I was confused at first but then noticed the asp tag in your comment. Anyway, I think I understand what you do there (get the object you want to focus/edit and set the focus on it). I guess I've to do something similiar. Thanks!

Comment: just as an update, I never managed to get it to work. I'm currently working on another part of the project.